# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Install mongo.so via config not installing

Tags: mongodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used to install mongodb extension via

```
  05-mongodb:
    command: pecl install mongo
    test: "php -r \"exit((extension_loaded('mongo') ? 1 : 0));\""
    ignoreErrors: true
```

but it seems like this this alone does not work anymore - did someone know what changed in the commands process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if something changed but we have following configuration and it's working just fine for a long time (today included), maybe `yes` makes the difference?

```
2-install-pecl-mongo:
    command: "yes '' | pecl install mongo"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: hmm... we have that for a bunch of other stuff - I'll try it on mongo too - maybe it's because of latest AMI update? Not sure, it seems like it's installing the extension but it's not restarting the apache or doing it after the fact. very odd behavior all the sudden.